# Convert dense tensor to ragged tensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have a Sparse Tensor which I converted into Dense Tensor. After converting from sparse to dense using `tf.sparse.to_dense`, I got an output which looks like this:

[image: Dense tensor]

I want to remove default values i.e zero and convert it to ragged tensor like this:
[image: Ragged tensor]
**Data in the above two images is different**

I went through Tensorflow documentation and I am unable to find any method to do this. I tried using `boolean_mask`, the major problem is to compute `boolean_mask` for each row individually.
So, I am wondering if there is an efficient way to achieve this.

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by "remove default values", i.e., how does your expected tensor look like after removing default values?

Comment: @greeness [[57, 69, 66, 64],[52, 65, 76], [63, 60, 57, 56], ... ] like this.

Comment: `scipy.sparse.lil_matrix` format has a `data` attribute like this - an object dtype array of lists - one list of nonzero values for each row.  But I don't know if the tensorflow sparse has anything like that or not.

Comment: that's called ragged tensors. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensors. Not sure what you are going to do with it in the downstream ops. You could use `tf.RaggedTensor.from_sparse()` to get ragged tensor from your `SparseTensor`. But as I mentioned, not sure if this is helpful for you.

Comment: @greeness Tf used to have a sparse_to_dense function (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_to_dense) in which we can give output shape required. They deprecated it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor** removes specific value from tensor of any dimensionality.

```py
x = [[1, 3, -1, -1], [2, -1, -1, -1], [4, 5, 8, 9]]
print(tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(x, padding=-1))


Output: <tf.RaggedTensor [[1, 3], [2], [4, 5, 8, 9]]>
```